# getting data from multi-value from element in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I accumulate values in a hidden field that I want to work with in a javascript function.

```
<input type="hidden" name="testing" value="10" />
<input type="hidden" name="testing" value="101" />
```

I believe that multiple values assigned to a single form field are treated like an array object in javascript. When I try to move the values into an array like this

```
var elemIDField = new Array();
elemIDField = document.formData.testing.value;
```

I get an error telling me the array is undefined.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there can be only one value attribute for any input control. what you  can do is value="1 2 3" i.e. append other values to the existing one with space and split it. there is no such thing "multiple values assigned to a single form field are treated like an array"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the array of fields. It is not an array of values until the server

```
var elemIDField = document.formData.testing;
vals = [];
for (var i=0;i<elemIDField.length;i++) {
  vals.push(elemIDField[i])
}
alert(vals.join(",")
```